# SQL Server merge: If two columns in source table are not equal then insert them as new records in one column of target table

Tags: sql-server, sql-merge

I have been grappling with an issue where i need to compare two columns in the source table and merge them into the third table as new rows if not equal. If they are equal then they are inserted as one record Example Below:

Source Table:

```
MIN_ID  MAX_ID
  1       1+
  4       2
  3       3
  3       1
  4       1+
```

Desired Target Table:

```
    MERGED_ID
     1
     1+
     4
     2
     3
     3
     1
     4
     1+
```

I tried using a merge to insert matched values and one value for non matched which inserted the same number of records into the target (either Source.MIN_ID or Source.MAX_ID)

```
    MERGE into [dbo].[Target] as A
    USING
      [dbo].[Source] as B
        ON
       (B.MIN_ID=B.MAX_ID)

  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET A.MERGED_ID=B.MAX_ID

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
       (A.MERGED_ID)
 VALUES
       (B.MIN_ID)
       )
       ;
   GO
```

This inserted 1.9 million records-same as source into the target (if equal then MAX_ID else MIN_ID).
But i still needed to insert Source.MAX_ID values into this table if not equal to Source.MIN_ID so i wrote another similar merge which runs as an endless query (55 minutes until i terminated the query, target table already has 1.9 million rows. First merge took 13 seconds)

```
    MERGE into [dbo].[Target] as A
    USING
      [dbo].[Source] as B
        ON
       (A.MERGED_ID=B.MAX_ID)

  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET A.MERGED_ID=B.MAX_ID

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
       (A.MERGED_ID)
 VALUES
       (B.MAX_ID)
       )
       ;
   GO
```

Can someone please advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look at your predicate in the ON. You are not referencing anything tableA. but of course you have obfuscated the real issue so much that I doubt this is a very accurate depiction of your real issue anymore. And what is the point of the WHEN MATCHED? It will just set the value the same value it already is. I can't fully understand what you are really trying to do here because your sample table is a single column with multiple rows with the same value.

Comment: The target table is initially empty. In the first statement the intent is that when source.column1 matches source.column2 then insert column1 value into target.column1. When not matched insert source.column1 into target.column1. The intent of the second merge is to then when target.column1=source.column2 then just update again as source.column2 value, when not matched then insert the previously skipped source.column2 values (in which source.column1!=source.column2)

Comment: If you notice the target table when source.column1=source.column2 then only one value is retained. When they are not equal then both values are merged into the single column.

Comment: Can you expand your example into something less vague than trying merge multiple rows with the same values where all values are already in both tables? And what does both values merged into a single column even mean? I can help you but you need to explain what you are trying to do here more clearly. I am just not getting it.

Comment: Modified the question to offer more clarity.

Comment: Maybe somebody else can make heads or tails of this. I give up.

Comment: @SeanLange  I'm sorry that i cannot post actual data because it is confidential. The first table contains a record where there is a MIN_ID and MAX_ID category under which the account exists. This needs to be split in a way such that if MIN_ID<>MAX_ID then instead of one record (or rule) for that account, the account is depicted by a consolidated ID (rule) field which holds the account's record for both MIN_ID and MAX_ID categories (having a record of the account for both the min and max thresholds of approval).If they are both equal then there exists only one category of approval for that acc.

Comment: Of course nobody expects you post real data. But what is helpful is when your data is something you can visualize. The sample you posted was so ambiguous it was difficult to understand the requirements. Next time take some time and put together some sample (and of course not real) data so it is more clear the intention.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I can understand how this would be ambiguous. Thank you for your feedback Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my issue by making things simpler for myself. First query modified as below

```
         MERGE into [dbo].[Target] as A
         USING
         [dbo].[Source] as B
          ON
           (B.MAX_ID=A.MERGED_ID)

         WHEN MATCHED THEN
              UPDATE SET A.MERGED_ID=B.MAX_ID

         WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
             INSERT
                (A.MERGED_ID)
             VALUES
                (B.MIN_ID)
            ;
          GO
```

Then i used a simple INSERT INTO SELECT STATEMENT to populate the other needed values

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.Target
       (MERGED_ID)

    SELECT B.MAX_ID     
       FROM dbo.Source as B
       WHERE B.MIN_ID<>B.MAX_ID;
```

Resulting in 1.9 million original records plus 450k extra records where both columns in source table were not equal

Comment: We tangled with the `merge` statement some time ago but moved back to seperate update/ insert statement because the merge was so enormous, complicated and slow. So I wouldn't say your solution is_more_ complicated

Comment: Meant that I made things simpler for myself! Typo!